# Using local variables out of loop scope

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, counter, local-variables

I've got a function to calculate the total value of any given cards, it stores the sum of all current cards into score. 
It also counts the number of aces in the deck. 
I'm having trouble linking the value of ace and score after the loop.
I've implemented print statements in my actual file, it calculates correctly, but score and ace are obviously filled with random numbers after the for loop.
I don't know how to use those values outside of the for loop.

```
    void calculateScore(Player * current_player)
    {
        int i, ace;
        unsigned score;
        ace = 0;
            score = 0;

        for (i=0; i<current_player->curnumcards; i++){
            if (current_player->hand[i].c_face == 0){
                ace++;
            } else if (current_player->hand[i].c_face == 10){
                score += 10;
            } else if (current_player->hand[i].c_face == 11){
                score += 10;
            } else if (current_player->hand[i].c_face == 12){
                score += 10;
            } else {
                score += ++current_player->hand[i].c_face;
            }//end if to check ace/jack/queen/king  

        }//end for loop

        if (ace>0){
            for (;ace!=1;ace--){

                if (score>11){
                    score += 1;
                } else {
                    score += 11;
                }//end if > 10 ace
            }//end for loop to calculate ace's
        }// end if ace loop 

        printf("Current score: %d\n", &score);

    }
```

Comment: This is suspicious: `score += ++current_player->hand[i].c_face;`. I think you meant `score += current_player->hand[i].c_face + 1;`, unless you intend to change the cards in the hand!

Answer (score 1):

you should printf("Current score %u\n", score); You are printing the memory address &score, where you just want score. And it's unsigned so %u not %i.

Answer (score -1):

```
ace, score = 0;
```

Takes the value of `ace`, does nothing with it, and assigns 0 to `score`. You probably want to assign 0 to both:

```
ace = score = 0;
```